# strip_tags() function is not working during insert records in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am inserting Register details of User through CodeIngniter but strip_tags() is not working in Codeigniter.
My Code is -

```
$u_name=strip_tags($this->input->post('username')); // strip is not working
$data = array(
    'User_Name' => $u_name
);
$this->db->insert('Table', $data );
```

If this can't then please say me option about strip for html tags.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make an example and the result that you expect?

Comment: seems to be clearly impossible...

Comment: can you get value of $this->input->post('username')?

Comment: insertion is done. but i want to strip of tags

Comment: Can you show an example input? like var_dump of post data and var_dump of "cleaned" data? I think problem is somewhere else, not in strip_tags function itself

Comment: strip_tags() function is running proper in simple PHP but not in Codeigniter. Suppose, if I insert value in textbox like - "<i>test</i> " \then the html / xml tags will ignore and store only "test" in DB.

Comment: strip_tags() is running proper in simple PHP but not in Codeingiter.  Suppose, I want insert username .Now I write <i>test</i> in textbox. then in textbox html , xml tags will be ignore and only "test" is store as username.

Comment: Instead, use a validation rule to do it for you. `$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');`

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this if it works or not:

```
$string = htmlentities(trim($string), ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your post data is being filtered **htmlspecialchars** or something like this (XSS filtering built in CI, however I cannot check it at this exact moment...). Try:

```
$u_name = strip_tags( html_entity_decode($this->input->post('username') ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use mysql_real_escape_string for inserting data to database.

```
$u_name=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('username'));
```

this should work as it worked for me.

Comment: This is irrelevant since it's escaped by default in `$this->db->insert()`